# R to detect accent

Tags: r, regex, regular-language

Is there a way using grepl or another function to detect all words that have accent? Not ignoring it, which has been ask many times, just to detect all the words that have any accent in it.

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide an example of which types of words should be detected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution - detect non-ASCII characters:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(txt, "[^ -~]")
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

where `[^ -~]` is a negated character class for ASCII characters (so, without negation, `[ -~]` matches any ASCII characters)

Or, using `dplyr` syntax:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data.frame(txt) %>%
  filter(str_detect(txt, "[^ -~]"))
         txt
1 aaaaaaaaaä
2   cccccccç
3    ccccccč
4     nnnnnñ
5       ynàn
```

Data:

```
txt <- c("aaaaaaaaaä", "cccccccç", "ccccccč", "abc", "nnnnnñ", "xXXXz", "ynàn")
```

Comment: Cool regex! This is very good but doesn't identify the position in the string of non-ASCII characters. For this reason I prefer the function `tools::showNonASCII`

Comment: Great regex indeed. Exactly what needed and very simple. I actually dont need to know the position of the character in the string, but is great to be aware of such function br00t

Answer (score 2):

In base R you could try:

data

```
txt <- c("aaaaaaaaaä", "cccccccç", "ccccccč", "abc", "nnnnnñ")
# fourth position doesn't have any accent
```

Find positions in vector:

```
grep("[\x7f-\xff]", txt)
# [1] 1 2 3 5
```

or boolean (`TRUE`/`FALSE`)

```
grepl("[\x7f-\xff]", txt)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

And to subset data:

```
# Only with accents
txt[grepl("[\x7f-\xff]", txt)]
# [1] "aaaaaaaaaä" "cccccccç"   "ccccccč"    "nnnnnñ"  

# Only without accents
txt[!grepl("[\x7f-\xff]", txt)]
#[1] "abc"

# could also use `grep()` instead of `grepl()` here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tools::showNonASCII` to detect characters that aren't in the ASCII set.  That includes accented characters as well as some symbols and characters from other alphabets:

```r
x <- c("aaaaaaaaaä", 
       "cccccccç", 
       "ccccccč", 
       "abc", 
       "€", 
       "$")

tools::showNonASCII(x)
#> 1: aaaaaaaaa<c3><a4>
#> 2: ccccccc<c3><a7>
#> 3: cccccc<c4><8d>
#> 5: <e2><82><ac>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Under the hood `tools::showNonASCII` uses `iconv`. I like this solution a bit better than using the regex `[^ -~]` because `iconv` replaces all non-ASCII chars with their hex byte representation, thus clearly identifying the chars in question

Comment: Thanks, but this transform the word with accent into the word without it in the output, which is not needed. But this is a great function to be aware of.